# How to write .tex files for single values in R to embed in LaTex flow text?

Tags: r, latex

I want to dynamically embed single values from my R analysis into my LaTex document. To be clear, I am not looking for a way to export tables, but really single values that I then can embed into flow text in LaTex.

Example:

> The average difference between treatment group A and treatment group B amounted to `EMBED PERCENTAGE VALUE PREVIOUSLY EXTRACTED FROM R HERE`.

What is the easiest way to export .tex files for single values from R? Or is there in general a better way to do that?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 2):

Have LaTeX like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

PI is approximately \input{pi.tex} and is related to circles.

\end{document}
```

And write `pi.tex` like this:

```
> cat(pi, file="pi.tex")
```

If you've got a lot of values to do, write them all to a single file like this:

```
\def \badpi {3.99}
\def \myage {21}
```

Then include that in your TeX header with `\input{Rvalues.tex}` and use them like `I am \myage\ years old`.

Or use `knitr` or `Sweave` to do fully dynamic LaTeX documents.